# Replacement in VIM with regular expression matched part unchanged

Tags: vim, regular-expression

Suppose I want to append two digit numbers in my file with "some_thing".

Like from this:

```
12 23 45
```

to

```
12_something 23_something 45_something
```

How can I do this using regular expression replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` is the whole match, so just use `&_something` in the substitute operation.

Comment: Is there a difference between using `&` and `\0`?

Comment: @Bernhard: not according to `sub-replace-special`, except varying by the `magic` option.